# Lightdm-gtk-greeter centre image

Tags: lightdm

I use `lightdm` with `lightdm-gtk-greeter`. Is it possible to modify the greeter so the login screen will centre a wallpaper image that is smaller than the screen? The image I use gets stretched to fill the screen. After I login the image is reduced and centred.

I'm using:
-Xubuntu 14.04.1
-lightdm 1.10.1-0ubuntu1
-lightdm-gtk-greeter 1.8.5-1ubuntu2~ubuntu14.04.1

I realize I could put the small image on a screen sized background as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe recipe an image, and save it and then use right click whit mouse and save it as desktop  background, and you can then reinstall lightdm again by enter this in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

and then reconfigure lightdm by enter in the terminal this:

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

and you can also install kde-full but it install a whole desktop called kubuntu a little difficult, and you can always autoremove it but it can change the background, and enter this in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get install kde-full
```

and you can also edit lightdm-gtk-greeter configuration file enter this in the terminal:

```
 gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and set a new wallpaper by editing background=(the picture that are resized), and remember to change the size of it, and it might work fine this two way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was hoping there was an option I could include in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` that I wasn't aware of. It's a small annoyance so I'll live with it.